# Error in my Subquery Factoring (WITH) Clause

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have an error when I run this script :

```
WITH q AS (
  SELECT COUNT(id)
  FROM   test
  )
SELECT 1, 
  CASE 
    WHEN q=0 then 'toto'
    ELSE 'titi'
  END

FROM   dual;
```

I must to use a Subquery Factoring (`WITH`) clause.

The idea is to display `'toto'` when the count equal 0 else I must display `'titi'`.

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in the question - it appears to be entirely SQL.

Comment: I've edited the question as there is no inline function in your query. There is one aggregation function `COUNT()` and there is a [Subquery Factoring clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2161315) `WITH` - which is what you appear to be talking about. If this is not the driver of your question then please rollback my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an alias for the result, and `FROM q`

```
WITH q AS (
  SELECT COUNT(id) as total
  FROM   test
  )
SELECT 1, 
  CASE 
    WHEN q.total = 0 THEN 'toto'
    ELSE 'titi'
  END

FROM   q;
```

Comment: please can I use a request after THEN  like WHEN q.total = 0 THEN 'select 'toto' from dual'

Comment: dont understand the question. I already told you you need use `FROM q`

Comment: Can I use a sub-request in CASE WHEN

Comment: I guess, yes. But not sure if is related to same question. Will need more details

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify it to:

```
SELECT 1, 
       CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 0 then 'toto' ELSE 'titi' END
FROM   test;
```

The error in your query is that you have created a named subquery `q` but then you are selecting the column `q` from the `DUAL` table (which does not have a column `q`).

You can fix your query like this:

```
WITH q AS (
  SELECT COUNT(id) AS cnt -- name this column
  FROM   test
)
SELECT 1, 
       CASE WHEN cnt = 0 -- use the column you named previously
            THEN 'toto'
            ELSE 'titi'
            END
FROM   q; -- use the named subquery q not the dual table
```

Comment: can I use please a sub request like WHEN q.total = 0 THEN 'select 'toto' from dual'

Comment: Yes, but it would complicate the query for no benefit.